# Quais as vantagens que a tipagem no angular oferece?

Tags: angular

Gostaria de desfrutar do máximo que o `Angular` pode oferecer. E uma das coisas que quero entender bem é **tudo** o que a `tipagem` do `Angular` me ajuda na hora do desenvolvimento.

Vi que uma das vantagens é que o `IntelliSense` no `Visual Studio Code` muitas vezes é ativado quando tipamos a informação com a qual estamos trabalhando.

Quais seriam as outras, estou estudando o `Angular` no momento e estou achando o mesmo incrível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim o `Angular` é um framework incrível. E agora na versão 4 está cada vez mais estável e conciso.

Mas a questão chave é a **tipagem**.  E o responsável por isso dentro do `Angular` é o **TypeScript**.

---

#### O que é TypeScript?

TypeScript é desenvolvida pela Microsoft, e é uma linguagem de desenvolvimento JavaScript em larga escala. Nela você pode escrever programas com estrutura de orientação a objetos, com interfaces, classe, métodos e atributos com nível de acesso, etc. Além de ter variáveis fortemente tipadas. O TypeScript pega o código escrito com a estrutura dele e transforma em JavaScript puro, para assim ser executado pelo browser, qualquer um deles, Node.js e por engines JavaScript que suportem ECMAScript 3.

---

#### Qual a relação do TypeScript com o Angular?

Para começar o `Angular` está escrito em `TypeScript`. Logo ao projetar a sua aplicação em `Angular` é necessário utilizar a linguagem `TypeScript` para criar suas classes, interfaces, métodos e etc. Vale lembrar que todo programa `JavaScript` **é um programa TypeScript válido.**

Site Oficial: [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

---

#### Quais as vantagens da tipagem do TypeScript?

Sem dúvida a principal vantagem é a verificação do código. Se você estiver trabalhando com uma variável do tipo `integer`, não será possível atribuir um valor do tipo `string` a essa variável, diferentemente do que aconteceria no Javascript Vanilla. Isso permite testar sua aplicação com mais facilidade, permite rastreabilidade de erros, e um código mais claro no que diz respeito as intenções do mesmo.

Temos ainda:

- O fator estético do código, que pode ser considerado uma vantagem por algumas pessoas.
- O fator apoio da IDE. Permite em tempo real, verificações de tipagem, erros de atribuição de tipos incorretos e etc. Neste quesito o Visual Studio e Visual Studio Code estão bem à frente da maioria.
- O fator comercial. Não podemos esquecer que por trás dessa tecnologia está a Microsoft, uma das gigantes no que diz respeito a desenvolvimento de software. Saber que seu framework é mantido por Google e Microsoft, trás credibilidade e confiança ao seu produto (Claro que isso é apenas um "blended", a qualidade do produto depende muito mais do desenvolvedor).
- Outros fatores: classes (melhorias), interfaces, mixins, módulos, enumeração, generics, parâmetros opcionais e com valores default em funções e afins, tuplas, union types, alias de tipos.

#### E desvantagens possui alguma?

Diante dos inúmeros benefícios, não acho que existam realmente grandes  "desvantagens". Vale a pena ressaltar é que o `TypeScript` adiciona um passo extra em cada alteração no código. É necessário **transpilar** da linguagem fonte para o JavaScript Vanilla que é a linguagem alvo, sem isso não há como executar seu código.

Answer (score 3):

Você tem essa `tipagem`, na verdade, graças ao [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). Angular 2 é projetado para trabalhar com o `Typescript`, que é basicamente um *`superset`* de Javascript que compila seu código tipado para Javascript puro. Toda a documentação `Angular` é escrita com base nele.

Dentre as [vantagens](https://imasters.com.br/framework/dotnet/net-o-que-e-typescript-e-quais-os-seus-beneficios/?trace=1519021197&source=single):

1. Porque você tem um `JavaScript` fortemente tipado;
2. Você aproveita conhecimento da `POO` para escrever melhores
   aplicativos `JavaScript` pequenos ou grandes;
3. O `Angular2` recomenda o uso do `TypeScript` para o seu desenvolvimento;
4. Equipes globais se beneficiarão do uso do `TypeScript`, visto que os erros podem ser detectados enquanto o código é digitado.

Assim, `TypeScript` é um super conjunto da linguagem `JavaScript` que fornece `classes`, `interfaces` e `tipagem` estática opcional.

Adotar o `TypeScript` pode trazer um ganho de produtividade e resultar em um produto mais robusto devido sua simplicidade e já consolidada ideia.